# Does a stored procedure always finish running?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2012.  Please see the TSQL below in preparation for the question:

```
create table PersonBatchTable (ID int identity not null, name varchar(30), complete bit)
GO
insert into PersonBatchTable ([name],complete) values ('Kevin',0)
insert into PersonBatchTable ([name],complete) values ('Adam',0)
insert into PersonBatchTable ([name],complete) values ('Marie',0)
insert into PersonBatchTable ([name],complete) values ('Craig',0)
--lots more inserts
go

create procedure StoredProcedureIHaveNoControlOver
as
begin
--Much more complex TSQL here
--Ends with the line below
update PersonBatchTable set complete=1
end
```

and the TSQL I have a question about:

```
 create Procedure MyProcedure
    as
    begin

    begin try
    if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#PersonBatchTableBackup', 'U') is not null drop table #PersonBatchTableBackup
select * into #PersonBatchTableBackup from PersonBatchTable
    delete from PersonBatchTable where ID not in (select top 1 id from PersonBatchTable where complete=0) --in reality this would say more like top 100
    exec StoredProcedureIHaveNoControlOver

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT PersonBatchTable ON
    insert into PersonBatchTable (ID,[name],complete)
    select ID,[name],complete from #PersonBatchTableBackup where ID not in (select ID from PersonBatchTable)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT PersonBatchTable OFF

    end try

    begin catch

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT PersonBatchTable ON
    insert into PersonBatchTable (ID,[name],complete)
    select ID,[name],complete from #PersonBatchTableBackup where ID not in (select ID from PersonBatchTable)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT PersonBatchTable OFF

    end catch

    end
```

As it stands the PersonBatch records will all be complete after the stored procedure has run four times - therefore after four hours if it runs every hour.

Can I be sure that the PersonBatch table will always be repopulated? The inner stored procedure takes ten minutes to run and can cause locks.  Hence I am seeing a lot of: "deadlock victim" errors propogated from the inner stored procedure to the outer the outer stored procedure.

Comment: I think if it errors, it will roll back to the previous state, so the table will STILL be populated because the DELETE will be rolled back, it won't be REpopulated though.

Comment: Without a deeper look into the issue, I feel like you probably should seperate the data used in this procedure from that live data and have only fast running updates to the live data so that there is no lock. Kinda like a document-orientated approach.

Comment: @JeffUK, can I assume that the row count of: PersonBatchTable will always be the same before and after each run based on the code in the question? Thanks.